# jquery appended elements

Tags: jquery

I have appended a div to my body

```
$('<div id="container"><img class="large" src="'+ img +'" /><a href="#">previous</a> | <a href="#" class="next">next</a></div>').appendTo('body').hide().fadeIn();
```

But i cannot interact with the elements that i;ve added if i try something like

```
$('a.next').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    });
```

it doesn't work .. how can i make jquery take notice of the appended elements ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to recognize current and future elements matching the selector, like this:

```
$('a.next').live('click', function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Why doesn't it work currently? This part: `$('a.next')` says "find `<a class="next">` that exist", then do something to them...but those links you're dynamically adding don't exist **at that time**, they're created later, so you need a different approach.

Comment: I was sure that the problem was caused by the fact that the content is later added but I didn;t know how to solve it. thx.

Answer (score 2):

you need to

- either defer attachment of the click handler until after the `a` tag has been inserted into the document
- or use jquery.delegate or jquery.live so that you don't need to care